# How to use R to backsolve which numbers are being summed to a total (like Excel's binary Solver)

Tags: r, excel, optimization, solver

I have some sales data by product and country.

I also have a subtotal described as 'Other products.' I would like to backsolve and work out which products have been included in the'Other products' subtotal.

This can be solved using Excel's Solver function. However the dataset is too large causing my Excel crashes.

I am hoping there is some way to solve it in R?

Some example data:

```
data <- matrix(c(0,10,0,5,0,3,6,2,0,1), nrow = 5)
rownames(data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
colnames(data) <- c("USA", "Canada")
```

Then with subtotals of 10 and 8 for USA and Canada, the answer would be products B and C.

I have a further complication that my subtotals are rounded numbers and the raw data is unrounded. So would ideally need a solution that allows for some margin of error.

Update (my attempt using CVXR):

```
data <- data.matrix(read.csv("goalseek.csv", header=TRUE, row.names = 1))
goal <- as.numeric(t(read.csv("target.csv", header=TRUE)))

nr <- nrow(data)
nc <- ncol(data)

'Quadratic Optimisation'
b <- Bool(nr)
objective <- Minimize( sum((t(data) %*% b - goal)^2) )
problem <- Problem(objective)
soln <- solve(problem)

rownames(data)[round(soln$getValue(b)) == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) lpSolve** Use the following mixed integer programming problem.  Note that we add dummy variables for each column that are each between 0 and 0.5 and additional dummy variables that are each between 0 and -0.5 in order to handle the rounding.

```
library(lpSolve)

nr <- nrow(data)
nc <- ncol(data)

objective <- c(numeric(nr), rep(1, nc + nc))

const.mat <- rbind(cbind(t(data), diag(nc), -diag(nc)),
                   cbind(0 * t(data), diag(nc), 0 * diag(nc)),
                   cbind(0 * t(data), 0 * diag(nc), diag(nc)))
const.dir <- c(rep("=", nr), rep("<=", 2 * nc))
const.rhs <- c(10, 8, rep(.5, nc + nc))

res <- lp(objective.in = objective, const.mat = const.mat, const.dir = "=", 
  const.rhs = const.rhs, binary.vec = 1:nc)
rownames(data)[res$solution == 1]
## [1] "B" "C"
```

**2) CVXR**  This uses quadratic optimization over binary variables:

```
library(CVXR)

b <- Bool(nr)
objective <- Minimize( sum((t(data) %*% b - c(10, 8))^2) )
problem <- Problem(objective)
soln <- solve(problem)

rownames(data)[round(soln$getValue(b)) == 1]
## [1] "B" "C"
```

### Update

Added ability in (1) to handle rounding.  Added (2).

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful. I particularly like the quadratic optimization solution. However, for my data set I get as a solution a vector of NAs. I've updated my post with my attempt at using your CVXR code

Comment: That is not reproducible since we don't have the csv file.